# Pattern issues weird warning

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching

Take for example

```
head[b_[PatternSequence[_, _]]] := 9
```

I know this example serves no purpose as is. It also happens in useful examples such as

```
head[b_[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg, b}
```

The definition is made propely, but it issues the message

> `Pattern::patvar:` First element in pattern `Pattern[1,_]` is not a valid pattern name. >>

A simpler example of the problem, suggested by @celtschk in comments

```
b_[PatternSequence[_, _]] :> 0
```

and

```
b_[PatternSequence[]] :> 0
```

Particularly interesting is an example @OleksandrR found, in which the mysterious numbering of patterns becomes more evident

```
(p : {a_, b_, c_})[PatternSequence[]] -> Null
```

> `Pattern::patvar:` "First element in pattern `Pattern[4,{Pattern[1,_],Pattern[2,_],Pattern[3,_]}]` is not a valid pattern name."

Comment: Really strange!  I'm looking forward to the answer to this one if it's not simply a bug.

Comment: The same message is issued with `MatchQ[
 head[xx[y, z]],
 head[b_[PatternSequence[_, _]]]
 ]`

Comment: I get the message twice from `MatchQ[
 head[xx[y, z]],
 head[b_[PatternSequence[__, __]]]
 ]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yeah, in the original code that made me come into this I got the warning twice, with a `PatternSequence[___, _?somethingQ, ___]` . You're with v8.0.4 too?

Comment: This works: `head[b : _[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg}`

Comment: @Heike, it's weird. `b` is not the head there, try parenthesising and it all goes down the drain

Comment: Version 7 here.

Comment: It is also issued for `x /. b_[PatternSequence[_, _]] :> 0` — note the absence of `head`. It happens neither for `b[PatternSequence[_,_]]` nor for `b_[_,_]`, so obviously it is triggered when a pattern as head is combined with a `PatternSequence` in the corresponding argument list.

Comment: @Rojo Do you mean this: `head[(b_)[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg}`?

Comment: Version 8.0.0.0 here.

Comment: @Heike, no, that's the same as without the parenthesis. I meant `head[b : _[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg}`  works but `head[(b : _)[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg}`, which is the same as in the example, doesn't

Comment: @celtschk, interesting. I'll add to that that it is triggered when a NAMED pattern as a head. If you remove the `b` it works fine

Comment: @Rojo your last expression is equivalent to the one in my last comment.

Comment: Try running `FullForm[Hold[head[b : _[PatternSequence[_, _]]] := 9]]` v. `FullForm[Hold[head[b_[PatternSequence[_, _]]] := 9]]`, they produce different outputs.

Comment: @Heike, yes. I think I assumed that your first comment was you trying to provide me with an alternate way of writing the same pattern that works, so I told you it was not the same. But you were probably just investigating variations of the problem, so I'll delete these extra comments

Comment: I see it. I'll post the answer in a moment.

Comment: Also it's essential that there's either more or less than one argument in the `PatternSequence`. `b_[PatternSequence[_]]` doesn't trigger the message, nor does `b_[PatternSequence[__]]`, but both `b_[PatternSequence[_, _, _]]` and `b_[PatternSequence[]]` do. Also, applying the replacement rule isn't necessary; already using the pattern in `b_[PatternSequence[]] :> 0` triggers the mesage (however just writing the pattern without the `:> 0` doesn't).

Comment: I'll be back in a bit. So, if someone else sees it while I'm away, feel free to post it.

Comment: @celtschk you're making the examples so simple that I'm starting to find this small "bug" more uncomfortable. Something like `b_[8 | PatternSequence[]] :> b` is totally common and issues the warning TWICE

Comment: However the pattern seems to work anyway: `{x[8],y[],z[3]} /. (b_)[8 | PatternSequence[]] :> b` gives `{x, y, z[3]}` as it should.

Comment: @celtschk Yeah, fortunately I think all examples work. So we'll just have to shut the message up for good perhaps

Comment: Guessing @rcollyer's forthcoming post `head[b_[_, arg : _PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg, b}` does not produce the warning message :)

Comment: @Rojo same for using `_[{x_} | x__] :> f[x]`. :^)

Comment: @kguler that's a different expression though and does not match the original pattern.

Comment: @kguler: However, `head[b_[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg, b}` *does* trigger the message. With the extra underscore, it gets another meaning: It matches as second argument an expression whose head is itself an expression with head `PatternSequence`.

Comment: @kguler sorry, it took much longer, and while I understand something about it, I'm not there, yet.

Comment: @celtschk and Mr.W, got it... I think :)

Comment: @kguler cool. Can't wait. I'm afraid I'm stuck.

Comment: @rcollyer, meant "I think I got Mr.W and celtschk meant" :) Wish I could say I have any clue re the original question.

Comment: @kguler we're discussing it in chat.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard but `_[{x_} | x__] :> f[x]` issues a proper warning. Btw, I like when I can use the same pattern name in alternative patterns

Comment: One way to remove the warning is to get the PatternSequence out of the inner expression, like this: `head[b_[dummy___]/;MatchQ[{dummy},{PatternSequence[_,_]}]] := 9`.

Comment: @celtschk, yes, but there sure is a time penalty. So far I wrapped the whole assignment in Quiet[..., pattern::...]

Comment: More than a workaround, I'd like to know WHY this message is issued.

Comment: Did you write to support?

Comment: @Szabolcs, yeah, just now. I'll comment after getting an answer

Answer (score 9):

This is a reported bug in the pattern matcher.

Comment: Did you report this yourself? Or, do you have other confirmation of this?

Comment: Yes I reported it

Comment: Alright, I had reported it today too. +1

Comment: +1 3 hours left for the bounty to expire. I guess I'll award it here. @Rojo I suppose this question should be tagged a bug then, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**Repeated (..)** command may help to solve some of the problems. I think the problem is about repeated patterns. All below examples works with no warning

```
head[b_[PatternSequence[_, _]]] := 9 (*err*)
head[b_[PatternSequence[_ ..]]] := 9 (*works*)
```

b_[PatternSequence[(_)..]]:>0

```
b_[PatternSequence[__ ..]] :> 0
```

b_[PatternSequence[(__)..]]:>0

```
head[b_[_, arg : PatternSequence[_, _]]] := {arg, b} (*err*)
head[b_[_, arg : PatternSequence[_ ..]]] := {arg, b} (*works*)
```

**EDIT 1**

```
head[___, b_[__, arg : PatternSequence[__ ..]]] := {b, {arg}}
head[f[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

outputs with no warning but trims 1 element opps!

```
{f, {2, 3, 4}}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
head9[___, b_[___, arg : PatternSequence[__]]] := {b, {arg}}
head9[f[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

outputs

```
 {f, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Comment: However both patterns are not equivalent. The second one matches `head[f[1,2,3]]` which the original one doesn't. Similar for the others.